# Mathematica ignores precision requirement when evaluating a Legendre function

Tags: numerics, bugs, special-functions, precision-and-accuracy

**Bug persisting through 13.1.0 [CASE:4953269]**

---

When attempting to calculate a certain associated Legendre polynomial within a given precision, Mathematica seems to ignore it if the argument is substituted  using a rule `/.`. For example:

```
myx = 76;
N[LegendreP[3, 3.`30, 3, x]  /. x -> myx, 30]
N[LegendreP[3, 3.`30, 3, myx] , 30]
% - %%
(* Outputs:
6.58293*10^6
6.58293007401529368546652483424*10^6
0. *)
```

I am particularly intrigued with the last result. I thought that maybe internally it does take the precision goals into account after all, but this persists even for different precision goals:

```
myx = 76;
N[LegendreP[3, 3.`30, 3, x]  /. x -> myx, 30]
N[LegendreP[3, 3.`3, 3, myx] , 3]
% - %%
(* Outputs:
6.58293*10^6
6.58*10^6
0. *)
```

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: ``LegendreP[3, 3.`30, 3, x]  /. x -> myx`` basically expands the polynomial first before plugging the value, and that route is prone to subtractive cancellation.

Comment: I guess I also do not understand why say `LegendreP[3,N[3,100000],3,x]` gives `(-15.*(1.-1.*x)^3*(1.+x)^(3/2))/(-1.+x)^(3/2)` involving machine precision numbers such as `1.`. Version 12.3. Not sure if this involves cancellations. For comparison, precision stays intact for `Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[-3,4,1-N[3,100000],(1-x)/2]`.

Comment: @J.M. I am not sure that it is cancellation though, or maybe I don't understand where it happens. `LegendreP` just seems to ignore the precision of its input if it is not infinite-precision.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean now, @Marco: if you compare the result of `LegendreP[5, N[2, 20], 3, x]` and `LegendreP[5, N[1/2, 20], 3, x]`, the latter contains numbers of the appropriate precision, but the former does not. Could you (or Patrick here) please report this to Support?

Comment: @J.M. I've submitted a report to Wolfram Support.

Comment: The case number from Wolfram Support is [CASE:4953269].

Answer (score 5):

I am also weirded out by `LegendreP`'s apparent disregard for the precision of its arguments; I am not sure that I can explain that.

However, a workaround is to write your own LegendreP-equivalent using the definition for `LegendreP` in terms of [`Hypergeometric2F1Regularized`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1Regularized.html) that is provided in the [documentation for `LegendreP`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendreP.html):

```
ClearAll[LPfromdef]
LPfromdef[n_, m_, a_, z_] := 
   (1 + z)^(m/2)/(-1 + z)^(m/2) Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[-n, n + 1, 1 - m, (1 - z)/2]
```

Let's check that they return the same results using arbitrary-precision input:

```
LPfromdef[3, 3, 3, x] == LegendreP[3, 3, 3, x]
(* True*)
```

The `LPfromdef` function respects the precision of its input whereas LegendreP does not:

```
LPfromdef[3, 3.`30, 3, x] /. x -> 76 // Precision
(* 28.2662 *)

LegendreP[3, 3.`30, 3, x] /. x -> 76 // Precision
(* MachinePrecision *)
```